# How can I add referrer tag to my React JS website?

Tags: html, reactjs, tags, referrer, referrer-policy

please guide me how to add referrer tags to my website.
I've looking for few hours with no sucess.
I also know that there is a thing named referr policy but no clue what it is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how can I set referrer tag to my website